# How to configure options for a systemd unit file?

Tags: systemd

The systemd blog contains two articles that advice against using /etc/sysconfig or /etc/default:

- http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/on-etc-sysinit.html
- http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-new-configuration-files.html

What alternatives are there to configure system specific options for a systemd unit file?

Options I've considered:

- create a template unit instead and use a specifier

The downside is that you need to specify the option every time the service is started. This is mainly useful to run multiple copies of a single service so it is not really applicable.

- override the `Execstart` of the unit file locally with a `unitd.d` directory

The disadvantage here is that this requires to override the entire `Execstart`. It cannot be used to simply specify a single option.

Answer (score 4):

It depends a little on what option you're trying to configure. If it's a folder location (like the home directory, runtime directory, etc.), systemd provides this through variables.

Otherwise, you can use an environment file to specify the options, and then have the service unit include the variables in those files. For example, the service file would contain the following (in addition to the usual parameters):

```
[Service]
Environment=ENV_OPTION_1=0 ENV_OPTION_2=linux
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/program-name
ExecStart=/usr/bin/program $ENV_OPTION_1 ${ENV_OPTION_2}
```

`EnvironmentFile` points to a simple file that contains key-value pairs, like so:

```
ENV_OPTION_1=8913
ENV_OPTION_2=ubuntu
```

`Environment` are default options you may want to have.

The environment values are then used in `ExecStart` as shown above. Note that if the value may be space-separated, you need to use the `${}` syntax.

Comment: The posts I refer to explicitely suggest to avoid using files in /etc/sysconfig or /etc/default. The EnvironmentFile option as used here is what I am using now and what e.g. sshd is using but which should be avoided if you want to adher to systemd "guidelines". Only those guidelines do not clearly state what alternative to use. Which is what I am looking for with this question.

Answer (score 3):

As I have said elsewhere (q.v.), the systemd people want you to use the snippet `.conf` files, and consider `EnvironmentFile` to be a bad idea and its use a mistake.

You can even have multiple snippet files:

```
# wibble.service.d/execstart.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/wibble $OPTIONS0 $OPTIONS1
```

```
# wibble.service.d/options0.conf
[Service]
Environment=OPTIONS0=--wobble
```

```
# wibble.service.d/options1.conf
[Service]
Environment=OPTIONS1=--wubble
```

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473035/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419061/5132

Comment: It's possible to "override" the systemd unit file by adding further configuration, and the unit files are merged together. Can you expand on that idea?