# How to override systemd unit file settings?

Tags: systemd

I have installed MySQL on my Arch Linux server. I moved the data directory to a place under /home, where my RAID volume is mounted. I noticed that mysqld will not start in this configuration by default since the systemd unit contains the setting `ProtectHome=true`.

I want to override *just* this setting. I don't want to re-specify the `ExecStart` or similar commands, in case they change when the package is upgraded.

I tried making a simple file at `/etc/systemd/system` called `mysqld.service` and added only these lines:

```
[Service]
ProtectHome=false
```

This doesn't work as it looks like the service in /etc *replaces*, not overrides, the system service.

Is there a way to override settings in systemd unit files this way without directly modifying the files in /usr/lib/systemd/system? (which is what I have done for now as a temporary fix, although that will end up reverted if the package is updated)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/659267/62688

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265281/5132 .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You may override a systemd unit file using

```
systemctl edit mysqld.service
```

Any statements made in the override file will take priority.

Comment: if only it wasn't interactive only ;(

Comment: @Hvisage it's possible to just create a folder and a file instead of running `systemctl edit` command. For example:
`mkdir /etc/systemd/system/coturn.service.d/
&& echo -e "[Service]\nRestart=always" > /etc/systemd/system/coturn.service.d/overrides.conf`

Comment: @Hvisage If writing the override file non-interactively, you may subsequently need to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

Answer (score 111):

[`systemctl edit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#edit%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) will create a [drop-in](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) file where you can override most of the settings, but these files have some specifics worth mentioning:

> Note that for drop-in files, if one wants to remove entries from a setting that is parsed as a list (and is not a dependency), such as `AssertPathExists=` (or e.g. `ExecStart=` in service units), one needs to first clear the list before re-adding all entries except the one that is to be removed.
>
> ```
> #/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/local.conf
> [Unit]
> AssertPathExists=
> AssertPathExists=/srv/www
> ```
>
> Dependencies (`After=`, etc.) cannot be reset to an empty list, so dependencies can only be added in drop-ins. If you want to remove dependencies, you have to override the entire unit.

To override the entire unit, use `systemctl edit --full`, this will make a copy in `/etc` if there is none yet and let you edit it.

See also [Systemd delete overrides](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449051/systemd-delete-overrides)

Comment: +1 for the tip about clearing `ExecStart`

Comment: +1 Do you know where this is documented? I mean specifically the altering/clearing/adding-to behaviour of drop-ins?

Comment: @AndreasT: this is a direct quote from the documentation linked to in the post ("[drop-in](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) file"). Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: As an addition: You can also override [systemd sockets](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) the same way: `sudo systemctl edit exampled.socket`.