# Systemd delete overrides

Tags: systemd

How can I delete the overrides file for a systemd unit?

I tried `systemctl edit myunit`, deleting all the text, then saving, but that appears to have no effect, with an error message ending with `canceled: temporary file is empty.`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The appropriate command is [`systemctl revert`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#revert%20UNIT%E2%80%A6), which will revert the given unit to its vendor configuration, deleting all overrides. (It will also restore the unit’s properties to their defaults, and unmask it if it was masked by the administrator.)

If you want the settings to be applied immediately, you need to restart the service ([`systemctl restart`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#restart%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6)).