# overriding lightdm.service from ansible

Tags: systemd, vpn, ansible, lightdm

I am having an issue with my GUI. I have setup a provisioned vpn via ansible that needs to be up before the graphical interface is up (lightdm on ubuntu lts 16.04).

So I read you shouldn't edit the lightdm service directly but do override on it. How do I override lightdm service on /etc/system/systemd ?

I know there are commands to override them,  but I need to know how to make this with files so that I make them tasks from ansible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override systemd unit file settings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398540/how-to-override-systemd-unit-file-settings)

Comment: not exactly, I am asking from an ansible perspective.

Comment: Do you need the instructions in Ansible to create the drop-in file, or do you need help creating the drop-in file, or both?

Comment: Both would be awesome as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from coreos systemd overriding (drop-ins) services and I could make the appropriate ansible directives.

Thank you all.