# Can't override a systemd unit's ConditionVirtualization on Archlinux on Distrod on WSL

Tags: systemd, arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd-timesyncd

I'm trying to start systemd-timesyncd on Archlinux that was installed via Distrod on top of WSL. By default systemd-timesyncd's unit file prevents it from starting up on virtualized environment, the unit file has a `ConditionVirtualization=!container` flag. I'm trying to override this with the following configuration:

```
[root@valentine ~]# systemd-detect-virt
wsl
[root@valentine ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
ConditionVirtualization=wsl
[root@valentine ~]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@valentine ~]# systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
[root@valentine ~]# systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
○ systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
  Condition: start condition failed at Mon 2023-02-27 10:38:46 CET; 6s ago
             └─ ConditionVirtualization=!container was not met
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)

Feb 27 10:38:46 valentine systemd[1]: Network Time Synchronization was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionVirtualization=!container).
```

It seems like systemd is picking p the override configuration, yet, it doesn't seem to use the overridden configuration flag.

What's the best way to solve this issue and have systemd-timesyncd run in a virtualized envrionment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and came across [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468067) which helped me.  It turns out that `ConditionVirtualization` takes a list of entries and must be cleared before it can be changed.

I used `sudo systemctl edit systemd-timesyncd` to create the drop-in file with this contents:

```
[Unit]
ConditionVirtualization=
ConditionVirtualization=wsl
```

And now it works as expected:

```
~ >sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-03-01 14:31:05 EST; 1s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 8816 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Initial synchronization to time server 137.184.81.69:123 (0.arch.pool.ntp.org)."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 19001)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─8816 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Mar 01 14:31:05 gnantel systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Mar 01 14:31:05 gnantel systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Mar 01 14:31:02 gnantel systemd-timesyncd[8816]: Initial synchronization to time server 137.184.81.69:123 (0.arch.pool.ntp.org).
```

I also did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to be safe but when editing using `systemctl` it is not supposed to be necessary.

Comment: Also, we could have just cleared the list.  I just came across this approach here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8204#issuecomment-1338334154

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. Lesson learned here: don't try to use systemd intuitively, read the docs instead. Thank you again.