# Is it possible to export env variable for some services?

Tags: debian, systemd, environment-variables

Saying that I have two services, which are to start two processes automatically while the system (Ubuntu 16.04.3) starts up.

One service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=service 1
Requires=init_mdc.service
After=rc.local.service init_mdc.service


[Service]
ExecStart=someCmd
ExecReload=someCmd
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
Type=simple
```

The other service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=service 2
Requires=init_mdc.service
After=rc.local.service init_mdc.service


[Service]
ExecStart=someCmd2
ExecReload=someCmd2
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
Type=simple
```

The two services need some same env variables.

For now my solution is not good, because the `someCmd`s of the two services are two different bash scripts, in which I set the same env variables.

I'm thinking if I can set some env variables in some place in some way so that the two services can share them, in other words, I want to set the env variables only once, instead of two times.

I've tried to export these env variables from `/etc/profile`, from `/etc/rc.local`, but they don't work. I think it's because the system runs my two services first and then `/etc/profile` and `/etc/rc.local` are read by the system.

Is there some way to allow me to set some env variables for more than one service file? I've known that we can set `EnvironmentFile=XXX` in the service file to import some env variables but I don't like this because I still have to set more than once `EnvironmentFile=XXX` for each service service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `EnvironmentFile=` is the way to go.

I don't understand your point on having to set it more than once... You have to set it once from each service that needs those variables...

Service 1:

```
[Unit]
Description=service 1

[Service]
ExecStart=someCmd
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/common.env
...
```

Service 2:

```
[Unit]
Description=service 2

[Service]
ExecStart=someCmd2
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/common.env
...
```

And keep all the `VAR=VALUE` settings in file `/path/to/common.env`.

The syntax of environment file is compatible to that of shell scripts, so you can even have source it in your `.bash_profile`

```
# ~/.bash_profile
if [ -f /path/to/common.env ]; then
    . /path/to/common.env
fi
```

---

One alternative is to use `systemctl set-environment` or `systemctl import-environment` to set global environment variables in PID 1. (See docs [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#set-environment%20VARIABLE=VALUE%E2%80%A6).)

You might still need `PassEnvironment=` to export those variables in specific services, but in that case you only need to list the variable names.

I really don't think this is the best solution though, I think `EnvironmentFile=` is much more self-contained, elegant and appropriate for your use case.

Comment: [The systemd people themselves do not like `EnvironmentFile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419061/5132).  A common, linked, `.conf` file augmenting both services with the same `Environment` settings would be preferable, I suspect.