# Passing environment variables around in systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, environment-variables

`EnvironmentFile` is not an option as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419061/198223).

I am trying to understand the recommended way of using and passing environment variables.

I have a `urxvtd.socket`:

```
[Unit]
Description=urxvt deamon (socket activation)
Documentation=man:urxvtd(1) man:urxvt(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/urxvt/urxvtd-%H

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Now a `urxvtd.socket` with a `Requires` dependency on that urxvtd.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=Urxvt Terminal Daemon
Requires=urxvtd.socket

[Service]
# Needs to know socket file location RXVT_SOCKET environment variable.
# Where will it come from?
ExecStart=/usr/bin/urxvtd -o -q

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now I need `RXVT_SOCKET` to be set before starting i3 as i3 will have a key binding to start `urxvtc` (urxvt client).

If I start i3/Xorg without systemd (i.e with xinitrc), and put in [`.zshenv`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Startup.2FShutdown_files) (user specific environment file loaded always.):

```
export RXVT_SOCKET=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/urxvt/urxvtd-machinename
```

Then `urxvtc` launched by i3 will correctly infer the RXVT_SOCKET variable and look for the socket at that path.

However, the `urxvtd.service` launches `urxvtd` (the daemon), so it also needs RXVT_SOCKET.

The Archwiki recommends setting the environment in `urxvtd.service`:

```
...
Environment=RXVT_SOCKET=%t/urxvtd-%H
...
```

But therein the problem lies. **Why should the environment variable be set again in `urxvtd.service`, when the initial user `urxvtd.socket` should set it?**

Note, it is set again in `.zshenv` for i3 to get it. **This is a case of multiple sources of truth for one simple environment variable.**.

Did we notice that `urxvtd.service` example above has the incorrect path for RXVT_SOCKET set in `.zshenv`? Reiterates my multiple source of truth argument.

What is the best way to deal with this?

I was thinking maybe I can set the RXVT_SOCKET in `urxvtd.socket` as so:

```
[Socket]
Environment=RXVT_SOCKET
ListenStream=%t/urxvt/urxvtd-%H
```

And since `urxvtd.service` is a dependency then there should be a way to import environment variable. But there isn't. So urxvtd daemon will behave as if RXVT_SOCKET is not set, but the socket will be created correctly due to `urxvtd.socket`.

Then I dug a bit deeper, and `systemctl --user import-environment RXVT_SOCKET` should import the variable across systemd units. Would that really be the way? Then I also need to ensure that the import happens *before* urxvtd.service runs. How would that work?

If I do use Xorg/i3 with systemd, I believe there should be a way to transfer the environment variable across systemd units.

**At this point I am likely to believe there is no pure systemd solution to such requirement for propagation of environment variables**

*I ended up using a shell to wrap the `ExecStart` command since the shell will inherit the environment correctly.*

Comment: In an ideal world, you wouldn't be worrying about this environment variable in the first place and `urxvtd` would employ the listening socket that is being passed to it as an already-open file descriptor.

Comment: You have a socket unit.  systemd is, right now, setting up a file descriptor to the designated socket, and the `urxvtd` program is starting execution with that file descriptor open and a `LISTEN_FDS` environment variable telling it how many such already-open file descriptors for listening sockets it has (1 in this case).  In an ideal world, `urxvtd` wouldn't be repeating all of this work and you wouldn't be worrying about the `RXVT_SOCKET` environment variable.

Comment: Did you ever found a soution to this?

Comment: @gxx Only this: `I ended up using a shell to wrap the ExecStart command since the shell will inherit the environment correctly.`