# creating OS environment variables using ExecStartPre on Systemd

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables, systemd-unit

I have the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Panel for Systemd Services
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pysd
Group=pysd
PermissionsStartOnly=true
WorkingDirectory=/opt/pysd
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir /run/pysd
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R pysd:pysd /run/pysd
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn app:app -b 127.0.0.1:8100 --pid /run/pysd/pysd.pid --workers=2
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /run/pysd
PIDFile=/run/pysd/pysd.pid
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=pysd.service
```

I would like to create an environment variable with `ExecStartPre` and then incorporating this variable to `ExecStart`.

To be more specific, I want to create an environment variable `GUNICORN_SERVER`, before running the `ExecStart`, and then using this environment variable for the option `-b` at `ExecStart`.

I tried something like `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'export GUNICORN_SERVER=127.0.0.1:8100'`, but no environment variable was created.

How do I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Why not just `Environment=GUNICORN_SERVER=127.0.0.1:8080`?

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to work fine, but I'm not sure of the results, when using `os.environ.get('GUNICORN_SERVER')` on my Python application. I have to review here.. Tks anyway, muru.

Comment: You really should read the Gunicorn doco.  It _documents_ a systemd service unit, the `RuntimeDirectory` part of which you have laboriously reinvented.  It also documents a systemd socket unit.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot use `ExecStartPre` to directly set the environment for other `ExecStartPre` or `ExecStart` commands - those are all separate processes. (Indirectly, by saving to a file and reading it or something, sure.)

Systemd has two ways to set the environment: `Environment=` and `EnvironmentFile=`. There are examples of both in [`man 5 systemd.exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/systemd.exec.5.html#environment). These affect all processes started by the service, including those for `ExecStartPre`. 
If these variables don't have to dynamically set, those are a good option:

```
Environment=GUNICORN_SERVER=127.0.0.1:8080
```

However, if you need to dynamically set the variables, the manpage says this about `EnvironmentFile`:

```
The files listed with this directive will be read shortly before the process is
executed (more specifically, after all processes from a previous unit state
terminated. This means you can generate these files in one unit state, and read it
with this option in the next).
```

So, one option would be to write it to a file in `ExecStartPre`, and have systemd read that file as part of `EnvironmentFile`:

```
EnvironmentFile=/some/env/file
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo foo=bar > /some/env/file'
ExecStart=/some/command  # sees bar as value of $foo
```

Another option would be to use a shell in `ExecStart`:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'export GUNICORN_SERVER=127.0.0.1:8080; exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn ...'
```

Comment: The systemd people do not like this.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419061/5132

Comment: @JdeBP interesting, and makes sense. I always found it weird to have an EnvironmentFile jutting into a cascading series of service files.

Comment: Also note that the systemd people would say to use a socket unit to describe the listening socket, and the Gunicorn doco actually has one.

Comment: Unfortunately writing it to a file in `ExecStartPre` doesn't seem to work because it actually reads that file before running the ExecStartPre's, one workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42841480/32453

Comment: Nice suggestion using `/bin/sh -c '...'`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the best approach, is to use the `--env` from Gunicorn, which creates an environment variable on the OS, which you can read and incorporate the data to your Python application:

On your unit file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn app:app -b 127.0.0.1:8100 --env GUNICORN_SERVER="127.0.0.1:8100" --pid /run/pysd/pysd.pid --workers=2
```

On your application (Flask, for example):

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

gs = os.getenv('GUNICORN_SERVER')
if gs:
    app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = gs                                              
else:
    app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = "127.0.0.1:8100"
```

Thanks for your comment, JdeBP. The [documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) has a lot of information, indeed.