# Env vars in /etc/environment not globally visible?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I am trying to create a `systemd` service;

This service has a script that is supposed to use some environment variables;

So I created this:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/atlantis-server.service 
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/atlantis-server.sh
```

Which points to this

```
pkara@atlantis-server:~$ cat /usr/local/bin/atlantis-server.sh 
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/environment
atlantis server --atlantis-url="$URL" --gitlab-user="$USERNAME" --gitlab-token="$TOKEN" --gitlab-webhook-secret="$SECRET" --gitlab-hostname="$HOSTNAME" --repo-whitelist="$REPO_WHITELIST"
```

What I noticed (after some errors in my `systemd` logs) is that I had to explicitly `source /etc/environment`

(this is where the above vars are declared).

Why is this needed?

Aren't they globally visible?

**edit**: Adding this to the service definition did not solve the problem

```
Environment=/etc/environment
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## `/etc/environment` is not a global configuration file.

It applies *only* on Linux; *only* to PAM sessions, as employed by `login` and so forth; and *only* in the case where a particular PAM plug-in is installed and enabled on the system, and where that PAM plug-in has not been configured to use some other file (because `/etc/environment` is merely its default if it is not told otherwise).   It is that PAM plug-in that reads it.

Otherwise, it is just a meaningless file in `/etc` that nothing uses.

Whilst you *could* set environment variables globally in `systemd-system.conf`, this applies to *all* services, not just to the ones that you are wanting to change.

Similarly, whilst an `EnvironmentFile` in the appropriate service unit(s) is a way to have systemd read a common file with a list of environment variable definitions, the systemd people discourage its use.  They regard `EnvironmentFile` as a bad idea, and its use as a mistake.

The proper way to do this per the systemd people is to set each variable in the service unit with an `Environment` setting, which *contains the actual environment variable name and value* to be set, not a filename.  This can either be directly in the relevant service unit, if as here one is writing one's own service unit to be placed in `/etc`; or be in a `.conf` override file, if one is adjusting a pre-packaged service unit in `/lib` or `/usr/lib`.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419061/5132
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016). [`systemd-system.conf`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016). [`systemd.exec`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Andrew G. Morgan and Thorsten Kukuk (August 2010). "[pam_env — set/unset environment variables](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html)".  *The Linux-PAM System Administrators' Guide*.  linux-pam.org.

Answer (score 5):

The following is offered to provide clarity on what ***/etc/environment*** is/does, when it's consulted and what package provides it:

```
whereis /etc/environment
environment: /usr/lib/environment.d /etc/environment
```

Feeding the results of `whereis` above, we confirm ***/etc/environment*** is a ***SystemD*** file:

```
sudo dpkg -S /usr/lib/environment.d
systemd, snapd: /usr/lib/environment.d
```

Consulting `man environment.d`, we are told the purpose of ***/etc/environment***:

"*The environment.d directories **contain a list of "global" environment variable assignments for the user environment.  systemd-environment-d-generator(8) parses them and updates the environment exported by the systemd user instance to the services it starts**.... For backwards compatibility, a symlink to **/etc/environment** is installed, so this file is also parsed.*"

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the previous answer - Systemd doesn't source that file when launching a service.

> Adding this to the service definition did not solve the problem

`Environment` is used for inline definition of envvars (ex. `Environment=KEY1=Value1`). To read from a file use `EnvironmentFile` directive. The file that `EnvironmentFile` points to should be in following format:

```
Key1=Value1
Key2=Value2
```

It shouldn't contain any **shell substitutions** or **variable interpolations** because Systemd is not a shell and can't handle that info properly.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your service configuration:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

@jeff-schaller please note this is not `Environment=` but `EnvironmentFile=` so you should not have deleted my answer. Indeed my answer does result in the variables from `/etc/environment` being made available to the service.

Answer (score -2):

No, environment variables is per-thread property, so no globally visible, just inherited from some parent or grandparent process. Systemd don't read that file when launching system service.