# Init script not picking up environment variable set in /etc/environment?

Tags: environment-variables, nginx, php7

What is the right way to set a global environment variable, such that it is picked up all processes, including those started via init.d (`service <service> start`), on Ubuntu?
Details:

I first saw this issue with PHP, but now see it is not PHP specific. Follows is the original explanation of what I am seeing.

In the `/etc/environment` I have set:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
SYS_ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

Then in the PHP configuration file `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` I have defined:

```
env[SYS_ENVIRONMENT] = $SYS_ENVIRONMENT
```

And then restarted php7.2-fpm. Then upon checking in the phpinfo page, the variable is listed, but not not with its value. It is defined and accessible in login shells.

I did try setting `clear_env = no` in the `www.conf` file, but that doesn't make the value available.

I am launching `php7.2-fpm` via `service php7.2-fpm start`, not as a child of my login shell.

What should I be doing to ensure an environment is available to all processes?

My Web server is Nginx and the OS environment is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: /etc/environment is applied after relogging

Comment: This is being launched via `service php7.2-fpm start`, so it should not be depending on my login shell? Have updated question to clarify.

Comment: Dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473001/env-vars-in-etc-environment-not-globally-visible/473035#473035

Answer (score 1):

It might be this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env

> By default, nginx removes all environment variables inherited from its parent process except the TZ variable.

You can use the `env` directive to explicitly allow nginx to pick up environment variables.