# set environment variable from sh script in systemd service file

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables

I am trying to use a ready-made bash script that sets env. This is the service that I'm trying to use:

```
[Unit]
Description=myserver service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/myserver/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh ;/home/ec2-user/venv/bin/python  /home/ec2-user/myserver/myserver.py 2>&1 >> /home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_myserver.log' 
StandardOutput=append:/home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_stdout.log
StandardError=append:/home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `myserverVars.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export APP1=foo@gmail.com
export APP2_BIND_PASS=xxxxxx
export APP3=xxxxxx
```

the variables in `/home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh`
are never set, and the server is started without the variables and this is wrong. I am trying to avoid using Environment key or Environment File.

Comment: Note that `Environment` is the native mechanism in systemd, and the service unit file is intended to directly contain environment settings.  The systemd people consider `EnvironmentFile` to have been a mistake, but conversely `Environment` _is_ the way to set environment variables, either directly or with drop-in "snippet" files.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557081/5132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want variables defined in a script file to be available to the parent environment running that script, you need to *source* the script, not execute it. Change your `ExecStart` line to:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '. /home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh ;/home/ec2-user/venv/bin/python  /home/ec2-user/myserver/myserver.py >> /home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_myserver.log 2>&1 '
```

See [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/22222) for details on the difference between sourcing and executing a script.

Also note that I changed the order of redirections. To get both stderr and stdout to the same file, you need `> file 2>&1` not `2>&1 > file`.

Comment: any way to format this long string to something readble ? with line breaks "\"

Comment: @user63898 I don't know, did you try it with line breaks? If they dont' work, please ask a new question since that is a completely separate topic.

Comment: Of course, the redirections are a bad idea in the first place, as service management systems handle logging standard output/error.  And there should be an `exec` in the invocation of `python`, to cope with the case that `/bin/sh` is the Bourne Again shell.

Answer (score -1):

For me this worked:

```
 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'MYVAR=xx exec /some/file'
```

Comment: ...except that they are *"trying to use a ready-made bash script that sets env"*, so hard-coding them independently in the systemd unit file risks configuration drift if someone edits the script but forgets to change the unit file.